# An Integral Inequality for Non-Negative Functions on a Probability Measure Space

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

This is actually a qualifying exam problem from Northwestern University in 2012.

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a probability measure space. Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two non-negative measurable functions such that
$$\lambda\mu\{f\geq\lambda\}\leq \int_X g1_{\{f\geq\lambda\}}\ d\mu$$
for all $\lambda\geq 0$. Show that
$$\int_X f\ d\mu \leq \frac{e}{e-1}\bigg(1+\int_X g\ln^+g\ d\mu\bigg)$$
where $\ln^+(x) = \max(0,\ln x)$.

The expression looks very confusing to me, since I don't really see where all these terms come from. I have tried to use the layer-cake decomposition to expand
$$\int_X f\ d\mu = \int_0^\infty \mu\{f\geq \lambda\}\ d\lambda = \int_0^1 \mu\{f\geq \lambda\}\ d\lambda + \int_1^\infty \mu\{f\geq \lambda\}\ d\lambda $$
and for the first part we use the crude estimate to get  1, while for the second part we use the assumption. But this will give me the bound
$$\int_X g\ln^+f\ d\mu$$
which still depends on $f$. I have also tried to replace the 1 by some $C$ and then optimize $C$, but it also seem to not give me too much progress. Intuitively the assumption says "the average of $g$ on $\{f\geq \lambda\}$ is at least $\lambda$"; I have tried to follow this intuition to use the assumption but went nowhere. Any help or discussion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a calculus inequality. See exercise 4.4.8 on page 239 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html (though I remember an error while doing this exercise before, so beware).